# Invoking @EJB from an abstract base class inside MDB and Jax-WS

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, ejb, jax-ws

I have the following set up of classes. I am trying to do same operations via two protocols - webservice based and JMS based

Inside an EJB module I have

```
public abstract class AbstractMsgListener {

    @EJB(name = "classLoadUtil")
    private ClassLoadUtil classLoadUtil;

    protected void doSomething()
        classLoadUtil.doSomething();
    }

}
```

There is an MDB

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "jms/myqueue") })
public class MDB_JMSHandler extends AbstractMsgListener implements MessageListener {

    public void onMessage(Message inMessage) {
        TextMessage textMessage = getTextMessage(inMessage);
        doSomething();
    }

}
```

I have a web service based on JAX-WS implementation like the one given below

```
@WebService(name = "...", targetNamespace = "...")
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
@XmlSeeAlso({ com.message.beans.ObjectFactory.class })
public class WebServiceImpl extends AbstractMsgListener implements com.message.beans.WebServicesPortType {

    @Override
    @WebMethod(operationName = "...", action = "...")
    @WebResult(name = "...", targetNamespace = "...", partName = "...")
    public WSDataResponse syncWSData(@WebParam(name = "...", targetNamespace = "...", partName = "...") WSDataRequest wsDataRequest) {
        doSomething();

        WSDataResponse response = new WSDataResponse();
        Acknowledgement ack = new Acknowledgement();
        ack.setMessage("Success");
        ack.setReturnCd("0");
        response.setAcknowledgement(ack);
        return response;
    }

}
```

The Abstract class is in a separate EJB module. The MDB and webservice implementation are present in a separate web application project. During execution, the MDB is working as expected. But the web service throws a NullPointerException. The reason is that the following code didnt work properly for Webservice

```
    @EJB(name = "classLoadUtil")
    private ClassLoadUtil classLoadUtil;
```

The classLoadUtil was not assigned any object. But the same is working for MDB.
I think I am missing something here.

Comment: The webservice is inside a web project that has the the dependency of the EJB project? Maybe the webproject is not finding the EJB in its classpath.

Comment: Yes It has. The MDB and webservice reside in the same project.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend go for a default implementation an see if it works.

```
@WebService(name = "...", targetNamespace = "...")
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
@XmlSeeAlso({ com.message.beans.ObjectFactory.class })
public class WebServiceImpl extends AbstractMsgListener implements com.message.beans.WebServicesPortType {

@EJB(name = "classLoadUtil")
private ClassLoadUtil classLoadUtil;
```

Then use the EJB **classLoadUtil** inside your **syncWSData** method and see if it works.

If it does work, then you can try the inheritance version.

If it does not work, then I think it's a **classpath problem** in the **webproject** of the WS class.

Comment: I already tried this approach(using private member). It didnt work. Moreover the MDB is also present in the same web project as the Webservice. So, What should I do I address the class path problem

Comment: how are you calling the webservice? Are you using SOAPUI?

Comment: Yes. Using Soap UI. The request is reaching the soap operation method. But The EJB lookup fails.

Comment: Humm..strange...let's try this...remove the "name" property. Let just the bare anotation: "@EJB"